# Terraform init: Error: failed to open temporary file with direnv

Tags: terraform, nix, direnv

I used [direnv](https://direnv.net/) to install programs from a [nix flake](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Flakes) like this:

.envrc:

```bash
use flake ~/Documents/nixdesktop/shells/myshell#terraformAndOthers
```

myshell/flake.nix:

```hs
{
  description = "Shells with terraform, jdk, etc ";
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils/master";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      in {
        devShells.terraformAndOthers = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = [
            pkgs.openjdk17
            pkgs.bashInteractive
            pkgs.terraform
          ];
        }
      }
    );
}
```

Then I ran `terraform init`, which failed with the following error:

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/google from the dependency lock file
- Installing hashicorp/google v4.44.1...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/google v4.44.1: failed to open temporary file to download from
│ https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-google/4.44.1/terraform-provider-google_4.44.1_darwin_arm64.zip
╵
```

Alternately, sometimes terraform is working for a while and then suddenly `terraform apply` stops working with error “failed to instantiate provider PROVIDER to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message:”:

```
│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│ 
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google: failed to
│ instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google" to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message: 
│ 
│ This usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
│ needs to be recompiled to support the latest protocol...
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: call `direnv allow` again to have direnv create a new temporary directory.

Explanation:

Terraform (and any go program that calls [`os.TempDir("", …)`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#TempDir) or [`os.MkdirTemp("", …)`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#MkdirTemp), or [`ioutil.TempFile("", …)`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#TempFile), or [`ioutil.TempDir("", …)`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#TempDir)) creates files in the directory returned by [`os.TempDir()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#TempDir), which is the value of the environment variable `$TMPDIR`. `$TMPDIR` must exist first, or else those functions give an error.

Meanwhile, direnv’s `use flake` [calls](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/v2.32.2/stdlib.sh#L1270) `nix print-dev-env`, and `nix print-dev-env --profile .direnv/flake-profile  ~/Documents/nixdesktop/shells/myshell#terraformAndOthers` prints a shell script which ends with

```
export NIX_BUILD_TOP="$(mktemp -d -t nix-shell.XXXXXX)"
export TMP="$NIX_BUILD_TOP"
export TMPDIR="$NIX_BUILD_TOP"
export TEMP="$NIX_BUILD_TOP"
export TEMPDIR="$NIX_BUILD_TOP"
…
```

Each time the flake is executed, `mktemp` should create a directory. But if `$TMPDIR` no longer exists, then you need to recreate it. I think `$TMPDIR` stopped existing because direnv cached the environmnet vars, but the temporary directory was deleted after a few hours or after a reboot. To fix this, re-run `direnv allow`.